# Javascript function before button submit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have to call a js function before asp-action is called on button click

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="post">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
              var x = jsfunction();
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value=@Localizer["Button"] class="btn Button"  />
                </div>
            </form>
```

I want to call the js funtion on click of the submit button and then it should proceed to the controller action method

Answer (score 5):

You can try as follow :

```
<form id='myForm' asp-action="Index" method="post">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
          var x = jsfunction();
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id='submitBTN' type="button" value=@Localizer["Button"] class="btn Button"  />
            </div>
        </form>
```

And call it's click event by jquery or js"

```
<script>
  $('#submitBTN').on('click', function () {
    jsfunction();
    $('#myForm').submit();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the form's `submit` event:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
const checkbox = document.getElementById('check');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    // can cancel the submit here if you want
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('not checked');
  }
  // do other stuff here before posting to the server
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="#submit">
  <label style="display: block">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
    <span>proceed</span>
  </label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```